# How can I convert List<List<String>> into String[][]?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list, arraylist

In my project I have a `List` that contains `List`s of `String`s (`List<List<String>>`) and now I have to convert this `List` into an array of `String` arrays (`String[][]`).

If I had a single `List<String>` (for example `myList`) then I could do this to convert to `String[]`:

```
String[] myArray = new String[myList.size()];
myArray = myList.toArray(myArray);
```

But in this case I have lots of `List` of `String` inside a `List` (of `List` of `String`s).
How can I do this? I've spent lots of time but I didn't find a solution..

Comment: Questions are supposed to show some effort, so I suggest taking what you consider to be your best effort and posting some information about what you tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks.. But I really didn't know how to do that..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote a generic utility method few days back for my own usage, which converts a `List<List<T>>` to `T[][]`. Here's the method. You can use it for your purpose:

```
public static <T> T[][] multiListToArray(final List<List<T>> listOfList, 
                                         final Class<T> classz) {
    final T[][] array = (T[][]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.size(), 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size(); i++) {
        array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.get(i).size()));
    }

    return array;
}
```

There I've created the array using [`Array#newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class,%20int...%29) method, since you cannot create an array of type parameter `T` directly.

Since we're creating a 2-D array, and we don't yet know how many columns you will be having, I've given the column size as `0` initially. Anyways, the code is initializing each row with a new array inside the for loop. So, you don't need to worry about that.

This line:

```
array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray((T[]) Array.newInstance(classz, listOfList.get(i).size()));
```

uses the [`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5b%5d%29) method to convert the inner list to an array, as you already did. I'm just passing an array as a parameter to the method so that the return value which I get is `T[]`, which I can directly assign to the current row - `array[i]`.

Now you can use this method as:

```
String[][] arr = multiListToArray(yourList, String.class);
```

---

Thanks to @arshaji, you can modify the generic method to pass the uninitialized array as 2<sup>nd</sup> parameter, instead of `Class<T>`:

```
public static <T> void multiListToArray(final List<List<T>> listOfList, 
                                        final T[][] arr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < listOfList.size(); ++i) {
        arr[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

But then, you have to pass the array to this method like this:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>();
// Initialize list
String[][] arr = new String[list.size()][0];
multiListToArray(list, arr);
```

Note that, since now we are passing the array as argument, you no longer need to return it from your method. The modification done in the array will be reflected to the array in the calling code.

Comment: When I saw the question, I remember your code review. Very nice answer (method).

Comment: +1 Although if I were writing this, I would pass an array to be filled instead of a `Class` instance to the method.

Comment: @arshajii. Nice idea. I'll try out that, and post it too, if get it to work. Thanks :)

Comment: @arshajii. That will still require me to pass `Class<T>` as parameter.  That will be needed to create the inner arrays, which is of type `T`.

Comment: You shouldn't have to. `array` is the parameter and, in the `for`-loop, `array[i] = listOfList.get(i).toArray(array[i])`.

Comment: @arshajii. Oh! great. Works fine now.

Answer (score 5):

```
 String[][] myArray  = new String[myList.size()][];
 for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
         List<String> row = myList.get(i);
         myArray[i] = row.toArray(new String[row.size()]);
 }
```

Comment: I would just change `ArrayList<String>` to `List<String>`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
String[][] array = new String[list.size()][];

int counter1 = 0;

for(List<String> outterList : list)
{
    array[counter1] = new String[outterList.size()];
    int counter2 = 0;

    for(String s : outterList)
    {
        array[counter1][counter2] = s;
        counter2++;
    }

    counter1++;
}
```

Comment: oops, people don't like the traditional way :)

Answer (score -1):

To init String[][], you should init the list(array) of String[]

So you need to define a list

```
List<String[]>  string = new List<String[]>();
for (int i = 0;....)
{
String[] _str = new String[numbers];
_str[0] = ...
string.append(_str);
}
```